# If $X$ is a set, prove $-X = \{x| x\notin X\}$ is not a set.

Tags: set-theory

I just begin to read a textbook on set theory. The textbook just describes 9 axioms for the ZFC set theory and then ask me to prove the following question:

> If $X$ is a set, define $-X = \{x|x\notin X\}$, prove that $-X$ is not a set.

I understand from textbook examples that $-X$ may be too "large" to be a set, but I just can't formally argue this. I tried some constructions like this:

Assuming $-X$ is a set, then by the axiom of separation $Y = \{x\in -X| x\notin x\}$ is a set. (I just imitate the construction of the Russel's paradox). But I can't find anything wrong with this construction.

Comment: $$\{x\in X : x\notin x\}\cup\{x\in-X: x\notin x\}=\{x: x\notin x\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ and $-X$ are sets then $X\cup -X$ is a set (by Pairing and Union), and $$X\cup -X=\{x:x\in X\}\cup \{x:x\notin X\}=\{x:\text{true}\}=V$$ is the universe of all sets.

If you've seen Russell's paradox then you know that $V$ is not a set (it is a proper class), so we are done.